# Strange error trying to query against an excel datasource in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am writing a report in SSRS that uses an excel spreadsheet as a datasource.  There is a column in the spreadsheet I want to do counts on named F2.  I want to use this SQL to perform the counts:

```
Select Sum(Case When F2 = 'I' then 1 end) as IncidentCount, 
       Sum(Case When F2 = 'R' then 1 end) as RequestCount, 
       Sum(Case When F2 = 'P' then 1 end) as ProblemCount
From [Ticket Detail$]
```

When I hit OK to exit the query designer, I get this error:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Sum(Case When F2 = 'I' then 1 end)'.
```

Can I not run this type of SQL against an excel datasource?  How can I get the counts I want?

Comment: No, you cannot query in this way. You can import that excel to any relational database and then query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle this fairly easily in SSRS itself through expressions. If you select * from the dataset, you would used an expression like this in your tablix:

```
=sum(iif(Dataset1!Type.Value="I", 1, 0))
```

And for a textbox it would look like:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Type.Value="I", 1, 0), "Dataset1")
```

Comment: Ye gods!  I hate it when I get so hung up on "why can't I do it this way?" that I forget there are other ways to get what you need.  Thank you kindly for pointing out this solution!

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but it doesn't.  I put in a textbox with this expression: = Count(DataSet1!Type.Value, "I") and I get an error saying that the value expression has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  Currently trying to figure out just what this error means,.

Comment: If this is in a tablix, it needs to be used outside of the details group, in the parent scope.

Comment: Oh, actually I think I've steered you wrong here. That second parameter of Count() should refer to the scope, not a value. You'll have to go a different route with this - I've edited the answer.